# JS - Adding classes when clicking on the <li> in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code, I want to change the class of div containing some text after I click on its name in the menu, and because I am beginner, I tried this and even though I know there are better solution (you can tell me those) I did this. Maybe it can be done somehow using anchors, I don't know.

```
$(function () {
    $("article span div").on("click", function () {
        $(".visible").removeClass("visible");
        var li_index = $(this).index();
        $("ul li:nth-child(li_index)").addClass("visible");
    });
});
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely with this

```
var li_index = $(this).index();
$("ul li:nth-child(li_index)").addClass("visible");
```

`li_index` needs to be treated as a variable, not a string (strings go in quotes).

You can do this one of 2 ways. This way requires adding 1 to `li_index` since `:nth-child` starts at 1 and `$.index()` starts at 0.

```
$("ul li:nth-child(" + (li_index + 1) + ")").addClass("visible");
```

or use `$.eq()` instead of `:nth-child()`

```
$("ul li").eq(li_index).addClass("visible");
```